# Loop through SQL results, outputting only set field_value

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I am using the following SQL query to pull table date from another database.

```
$query = "SELECT option_value FROM db_name.wpm_options where option_name like 'options_go_tracking_%_tracking_pixel'";

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
```

Everything is connecting fine and the results of the query return as expected.  I am a little unsure as to how I can now loop through the results of the query, I think a **foreach** function is required but being a novice with sql I am having trouble proceeding.

The name of the field is "option_value", would this be used in the foreach?

My attempt to far is below, the echo is being output 10 times and there are 10 records in the sql query so I must be close, just need to output the data within the field.

```
    $query = "SELECT option_value FROM db_nameprivate.wpm_options where option_name like 'options_go_tracking_%_tracking_pixel'";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

    if($results):
    foreach($results as $row): setup_postdata($row);

        echo "output";
        // Trying to output the results of query here, the content of each "option_value" field


    endforeach;
    else: '.echo "No Records Found".';
    endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress, the `$wpdb->get_results($query)` returns an array of objects with properties that represent their associated column names. When iterating over a result-set, you can simply access the column by its associated property, just like this:

`echo $row->option_value`

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
$query = "SELECT option_value FROM db_name.wpm_options where option_name like 'options_go_tracking_%_tracking_pixel'";

$results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results) {
    echo $row['option_value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT option_value FROM db_nameprivate.wpm_options where       option_name like 'options_go_tracking_%_tracking_pixel'";
 $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

if($results){
foreach($results as $row) {

    echo $row['option_value'];
     // Trying to output the results of query here, the content of each  "option_value" field
}
}
```